# How to delete photos from the iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

How to delete photos from the iOS simulator? I have XCode 6.4

I have been testing an app and I have too many photos. I just need to put order and delete some manually.

I have found some answers on how to "ADD" photos and they talk about going to ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/
but I do not have that. I have
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Library/...

Probably that answers are old? I cannot apply the rest of the answers to "DELETE" either.

Comment: Reset content and settings?

Comment: Write an iOS app that does it?

Comment: Not an app, just delete manually only some photos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest way to delete all of your photos is to launch simulator and iOS Simulator > Reset Contents and Settings...
Then all your compiled apps will be gone as well.

Another way is to go to Photos app in Simulator and delete them like you would on a phone. Open photo and hit Trash Can icon on the bottom or choose Select on top, select photos you want to delete and then hit Delete.

Comment: How to do this with command line?

Answer (score 2):

You can go into the photos app as you would on a real device and select and delete the ones you don't want. Then delete them for good in the Recently Deleted album. It's a manual process, but it works.

When you reset the simulator, the default images will return.